# How to animate background image on page load in drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I have a site in Drupal 7 and I am using background image here.

I need to animate this image when page load, only one time. I used slider for this but for single image slider not giving any animation.

Comment: Check this one.. [Animate your Drupal 7 site, use spritely!](http://rainnic.altervista.org/content/animate-your-drupal-7-site-use-spritely)

Comment: I have installed the module. But not getting how to apply this on my sit..Coz no read me file exist.. Have you used this module?

Comment: I need something this type of animation when page load http://us.louisvuitton.com/eng-us/stories/patina#/home